# Display inspect element in a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, developer-tools

Something out there who had displayed the rendered html of a page in a div..

Lately I had develop a simple CMS for page meta taggings (dynamically add meta tags according to db record). All goes okay until SEO teams want a proof that it was 'really' rendering the metas.. I can prove to them using the developer tools but they do not want to manually press the `F12` and check if the meta was rendered. They do want to display directly on screen e.g`div`.

And I have no idea where to start. Excluding my situatuon, Is it possible to grab the data in developer tools and display it on a `div` or `iframe`? Or the `view source maybe`?

I am searching for possible solution to this but unluckily, cant find one using javascript, jquery, php.

Comment: You're saying that your SEO teams want you to output the contents of your meta tags to a div so that they can see it? This seems totally ludicrous unless it's confined to a local/dev environment only. Tell them to get over it and use the inspector!!

Comment: @scrowler Yes thats the thing I had explained but they are `THINGKING` if there are hundred of pages.

Comment: That could be done using a simple JavaScript that loops through the meta elements and displays their values in a dynamically created element … f.e. as a bookmarklet, or embedded into the page in a way that it runs only under specific circumstances (f.e. a specific cookie being present). But on the other hand – there’s tools for that kind of stuff already, that show you all kinds of info relevant to SEO about your page … if your SEO people don’t know/use any such tools, they are probably not worth their money :-)

Comment: I'd tell **them** to write a parser to run your pages through, it shouldn't be your responsibility to be irresponsible.

Answer (score 0):

You could propose to make [bookmarklets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) that your SEO team can run that would make JS alerts of meta tag innerHTML.

Otherwise as one comment says, they should just press Ctrl+U, Ctrl+F, type "meta", press enter, and get over it.